# How to use a resource?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a question about getting the resource id of a resource file.

I added a resource file(gif file) to the resources but I have no idea how I can obtain the resource id.

I tried looking for it in tools -> embedded resources but it does not show up in there. Also in the properties of the file the id does not show up.

How to access my resource?

Answer (score 3):

Images added to the `Resources` node in the AOT does not get a resource Id. And it does not make it embedded. Embedded in this sense means stored in the ax32.exe!

For MorphX reports there are [other ways](http://daxrunbase.blogspot.dk/2010/08/image-resources-in-reports.html) to use the resource:

```
display Bitmap footerImage() 
{
    return SysResource::getResourceNodeData(SysResource::getResourceNode(resourceStr(MyImage))); 
}
```

For forms fx. on FormButton set the following attributes:

- ImageLocation: AOTRessource
- NormalImage: MyImage (or whatever)

Comment: Thanks for the help but this does not seem to work for me. I am trying to use this display method in a listpage. When I try to display the Bitmap the listpage will not start up anymore it freezes and crashes my ax client.

Comment: Do not use a GIF image, convert the image to PNG. Then reimport the image.

Comment: To reproduce make a small form using your resource, export your resource and form. Then upload.